# Why do I need to have a runnable instead of calling directly from main?

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

Simple code from java.sun:

```
public class BasicApp implements Runnable {

    JFrame mainFrame;
    JLabel label;

    public void run() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("BasicApp");
        label = new JLabel("Hello, world!");
        label.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                mainFrame.setVisible(false);
                // Perform any other operations you might need
                // before exit.
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        mainFrame.add(label);
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable app = new BasicApp();
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(app);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I can put all of this method into main(), but why do I need a separate run method that also implements the runnable to execute it? What is the idea behind this concept? Thanks.

Comment: you *can* also put the code in a single line

Comment: `Runnable` is about concurrency, isn't it?

Comment: @KerrekSB In this case, yes it is about running "Swing stuff" on the EDT.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Oracle SDN: [Threads and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html)

> Once a Swing component has been realized, all code that might affect or depend on the state of that component should be executed in the event-dispatching thread.

The gist of it is that the code needs to be run when Swing is good and ready to run it.  Not necessarily right when you call it.

Answer (score 1):

Method run() is started in separated Threads. So your GUI part work "standalone" from other application and don't stop it during drawing.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to run  your code in threads, then you'd need to implement the `runnable` interface. When you implement the `runnable` interface, you need to implement the `run()` method.